# How to use <Tab> to indent code in select mode?

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to map `<Tab>` in select mode to indent my selection.

So I have this:

```
$ vim -u /dev/null
:set nocompatible
:behave mswin
:xnoremap <Tab>   >gv
:xnoremap <S-Tab> <gv
:snoremap <Tab> <C-g>>gvV<C-g>
:snoremap <S-Tab> <C-g><gvV<C-g>
```

The idea is to switch to `S-LINE` or `V-LINE` when identing. The problem with the above mapping is the `V` will toggle between `VISUAL` -> `V-LINE` -> `NORMAL`.

How can I correct these mappings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual mode, you only need one `>` to indent. `>>` is the normal mode command. Also, `V` turns a non-linewise selection into a linewise one, but if the selection already is linewise, visual mode will end. Better drop that. These changes result in:

```
snoremap <Tab> <Esc>gv>gv<C-g>
```

Actually, you can further simplify; there's no need to leave select mode and then restore the selection in visual mode via `<Esc>gv`; just use `<C-g>` to switch from select to visual mode:

```
snoremap <Tab> <C-g>>gv<C-g>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, You actually pointed out my issue the `>>`. I have completed my question and your answer is no more valid. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Ohhhh :( Actually this is a lot more complex that I thought... Going on linewise mode is complicated because if you select one line with `<S-Down>`, when you go on linewise mode, you actually select two lines instead of one...

Comment: Why would you explicitly switch to linewise mode? Indenting via `>` is linewise, anyway, regardless of the selection type.

Comment: On other visual editors (Sublime/Notepad++/VisualStudio/...) when you select a part of several lines and you indent it, the selection mutates to linewise selection. It makes sense because you cannot really indent a part of the selection, but the whole lines. This is just for visual comfort

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, there is a way, but you'd either have to write a function, or use a `:map <expr>`, and check the output of `visualmode()` if it is already linewise (i.e. returns `V`), and only if not force linewise with `gvV`.